# The order by clause invalid in views

Tags: sql, sql-server

The output of the script below is:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Any headsup?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
       SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) [Order]  
       FROM
       (
              SELECT

                     A.[ID],
                     B.[UID],
                     C.[Date] 
              FROM Sample_1 A
              FULL JOIN Sample_2 B
              ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]
              FULL JOIN Sample_3 C
              ON A.[ID] = C.[ID]
              WHERE A.[SourceFile] BETWEEN 1 AND 100
              order by [ID]
       ) a
       WHERE [Date] < '2018/02/16' 
) b
WHERE [Order] = 1  
ORDER BY [ID],[Date]
```

Comment: and question is?

Comment: This is according to the ANSI SQL standard specification. Specify ORDER BY when you select from the view.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me....

Comment: @RadimBača: To the error.

Comment: I mean, what is your problem exactly? Error can be simply removed by removing the `ORDER BY`. Apparently, this is not sufficient solution for you. Therefore, what is your goal? What are you trying to achieve and what is sufficient solution for you?

Comment: the error is clear, you may not use `order by` in views. That is so in every database. Just remove the order by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this instead as `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline
>   functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
       SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Date] DESC) [Order]  
       FROM
       (
              SELECT

                     A.[ID],
                     B.[UID],
                     C.[Date] 
              FROM Sample_1 A
              FULL JOIN Sample_2 B
              ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]
              FULL JOIN Sample_3 C
              ON A.[ID] = C.[ID]
              WHERE A.[SourceFile] BETWEEN 1 AND 100
              --order by [ID] (this is the cause of the error) 
       ) a
       WHERE [Date] < '2018/02/16' 
) b
WHERE [Order] = 1  
ORDER BY [ID],[Date]
```

Comment: Meaning the order by in sub-query is irrelevant?

Comment: @John: Hi John, i think the error speaks for itself. that the order by is invalid in views, subquery, CTE....(Sub-query is a query (select statement) embedded in another query). Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

agree with @Sparky in my case with this sql today.

```
d_e62 <- db_read(con, 
"select top 100 percent
campus2,
avg(fg) as mfg,
avg(cpw) as mcpw,
avg(LOS) as mlos

from
danall

where
ARDRG70 like 'E62%'
and w22wiesfund = 'Y'

group by
campus2

order by campus2")
```

The top 100 percent let me include order by otherwise getting that above error.

Answer (score -1):

Seems there is some confusion as to my answer.   I am suggesting that the op adds the **select top 100 percent *** to allow the view to be created.   I am not suggesting they remove the order by

**See example below**

```
create view dbo.TestView1
as
select * from ls.models order by model_number
-- The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
go
create view dbo.TestView2
as
select top 100 percent * from ls.models order by model_number
go
select * from dbo.TestView2
```

To fix the "issue", use the following code snippet

```
 SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
                     A.[ID],
                     B.[UID],
                     C.[Date] 
              FROM Sample_1 A
              FULL JOIN Sample_2 B
              ON A.[ID] = B.[ID]
              FULL JOIN Sample_3 C
              ON A.[ID] = C.[ID]
              WHERE A.[SourceFile] BETWEEN 1 AND 100
              order by [ID]
```

Comment: why top? I don't want to select top 100%..but then *

Comment: TOP 100% allows you to use an order by in a view...   The WHERE condition still applies..    Adding TOP 100% does not change the rows returned at all

Comment: This suggestion is both pointless and effectively incorrect. The optimizer is smart enough to ignore the top 100% part. And nothing guarantees order in a resultset outside of the inclusion of an order by clause in the query that generates it. Even if less than all rows were selected, order is not guaranteed as the order by clause is only used to satisfy the top directive.

Comment: I am  not suggesting that he removes the ORDER BY clause.   If you want to include ORDER BY in a view, one way to do so is by adding the SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT syntax.      The answer is accurate.